# change constant value on dll from xmlfile after debug it

Tags: c#, class, templates, constants, t4

i have code for class dll file which have constant could i bypass this constant from xmlfile after debug this dll , main point this dll used o another software so i need when software use tis dll constant change according to xmfile content.

[image]

```
public class UserInterfaceDefinitions
{
    public const string Plugin4 = ValidationConstants.Plugin4_text;
}
```

`

Comment: My xmlfile content <ValidationConstants>
  <Constant>
    <Name>Plugin4_text</Name>
    <Type>string</Type>
    <Value>
           @"        tab_page("""", ""tkIS_infra_Network"", 1)" + "\n" +
      "{\n" +
      //@"    attribute("""", ""Profile"", label, ""%s"", none, none, ""0"", ""0"", 182, 12)" + "\n" +
      //@"    attribute("""", ""Material"", label, ""%s"", none, none, ""0"", ""0"", 282, 12)" + "\n" +
      //@"    picture(""EndPlate_5"", 0, 0, 328, 35)" + "\n" +
    </Value>
  </Constant>
</ValidationConstants>

Comment: If it is really a constant (is declared as `const` in dll code, as you show) there is nothing you can do, its value is just substituted into every point where you use it in your code at compile-time. You can, however, make it not a `const` and get it from xml then.